# The project is not registered in applicationhost.config on IIS Express , VS 2015, 2017

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I need change some confing on my project in iis express
 When i opened C:\Users\Documents\IISExpress\config -> applicationhost.config file

I can not see  site element of my projects.
There is only one site element in this file and its  is:

```
<sites>
            <site name="WebSite1" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
                <application path="/">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_SITES_HOME%\WebSite1" />
                </application>

            </site>
            <siteDefaults>
                <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\Logs" />
                <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\TraceLogFiles" enabled="true" maxLogFileSizeKB="1024" />
            </siteDefaults>
            <applicationDefaults applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" />
            <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
        </sites>
```

And when a new project is created, the file specification will not be logged.

I use vs 2015 , where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS2015 uses the file under your solution folder .vs\config\applicationHost.config.

By the way, Jexus Manager allows you to manage IIS Express settings with UI,

http://jexusmanager.com

Add the solution file or config file as a new server and then you can see the settings visually.